# What is the problem with assigning magic numbers to named structure members?

Tags: c, clang-tidy, magic-numbers

Consider the following code:

```
const double Motor_Kv = 1.1e5; // Motor constant, [rpm/V]
const double Motor_R = 2e-2;   // Winding resistance, [Ohm]
const double Motor_J = 3e-6;   // Rotor angular mass, [kg*m2]
```

This has been refactored to use a structure:

```
const MotorParams Motor = {
    .Kv = 1.1e5, // Motor constant, [rpm/V]
    .R = 2e-2,   // Winding resistance, [Ohm]
    .J = 3e-6,   // Rotor angular mass, [kg*m2]
};
```

However, now `clang-tidy` is unhappy about the use of "magic numbers":

> warning: 1.1e5 is a magic number; consider replacing it with a named constant [readability-magic-numbers]

I know I can silence unwanted warnings with `// NOLINT` comments, but I would like to understand the reasoning behind the warnings. Is there a situation where the code from the second sample could lead to an error, while the first sample would have been safe?

Comment: The potential [maybe theoretical] problem is that in another part of your code you have another mention of the value `1.1e5` (for the same entity) and then both places must be kept in sync. This problem is solved if you use a `const` like `Motor_Kv` to hold this value, and all your other code pieces only use `Motor_Kv`.

Comment: The warning means do not use hard coded constants (but only named constants). In the first you name a constant. In the second you _assign_ a hard coded constant to a field (`Kv` and such).  As opposed to `const MotoerParam,Moter = { 1.1e5, ....}` - which would be ugly of course. One would need to make a change request for this; to not give a warning here.

Comment: This is not related to the struct at all. I wonder why you did not get the same message when you assigne the same magic numbers to your separate variables.

Comment: @wohlstad Other parts of the code will use `Motor.Kv`. If they use `1.1e5`, that would be a magic number in those parts of the code.

Comment: @Gerhardh I didn't get the message because all those "variables" are actually named constants.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev I think you are right. I guess the writers of clang-tidy did not handle a const struct of fields in this respect.

Comment: @JoopEggen `const MotorParams Motor = { 1.1e5, ....}` also produces magic number warnings. And it's actually inferior in terms of readability.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I messed up with `cosnt` qualifiers in my code which resulted in the parameter structure not being actually constant. Once that was fixed, `clang-tidy` accepted it without a whim.

Comment: I totally agree with your readability comment (of course). Thanks for reassuring that no ChangeRequest on the warning is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Static analysers can't understand what is said in comments, and so they might frown on any use of "magic numbers". You can prevent this by doing something along the lines of:

```c
#define MOTOR_RPM_V         1.1e5  // Motor constant, [rpm/V]
#define MOTOR_WINDRES_OHM    2e-2  // Winding resistance, [Ohm]
#define MOTOR_ANGMASS_KG     3e-6  // Rotor angular mass, [kg*m2]

const MotorParams Motor = {
    .Kv = MOTOR_RPM_V,
    .R  = MOTOR_WINDRES_OHM,
    .J  = MOTOR_ANGMASS_KG,
};
```

Comment: I don't expect static analyzers to understand comments, only the `const` keyword. Why do you think that `#define`s are more readable than `const` variables?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The main advantage is that you can gather all defines at one place, in some header "motor.h" and then you only need to tweak all relevant constants from one single place in the code. Also, in case these are important to know for the user of your code, then they shouldn't need to go chase them down in a .c file but find them in a public .h file.

Comment: This advice assumes that .c files are bloated to the point you have to "chase down" relevant constants, and header files are kept clean. In a project which has a separate `config.c` file and header files filled with inline functions, the situation would be opposite.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No this advise assumes that industry standard program design is used: a single public header, optionally some private headers, and then a number of .c files all considered private. None of it has anything to do with complexity, just information hiding and private encapsulation.

Answer (score 1):

A constant value is denoted a "magic number" when the static analyzer thinks it comes out of nowhere.

To fix this issue you can either use a define or a const  variable which will hold these values like:

```
#define MOTOR_SPEC_KV 1.1e5
```

Or like:

```
static const double MOTOR_SPEC_KV = 1.1e5;
```

And then use it into your structure:

```
const struct MotorParam params = {
    .Kv = MOTOR_SPEC_KV,
    ....
};
```

Or change the analysis rules to ignore this type of warning.